# Function e^x returns 'inf' as output when x is larger then 0.6

Tags: c, math, double

I tried to implement this code and it works to a certain point (x<0.6). I am just wondering why it ouputs 'inf' although the stop criteria should terminate the program when it reaches the maximum accuracy of double.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double fak(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    int i = 0;
    
    do {
        i++;
        f *= i;
    } while(i<n);
    
    return f;
}

double func_e() {
    double res = 0;
    double res_old = 0;
    double x, k;
    x = 1;
    k = 0;
    
    do {
        res_old = res;
        res += ((pow(x,k)) / fak(k));
        k++;
    } while(res != res_old);
    
    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    //printf("power %f", pow(3,3));
    
    printf("%f", func_e());
    //printf("%f", fak(3));
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `res != res_old` is never true. You can chek that easily by adding a printf.

Comment: Check the return value of your function `fak`. It will overflow and at a certain point return 0. The division by 0 results in `inf`.

Comment: Well, it works for x <= 0.6. So there is a point when `res != res_old` is true. But I do not get why it is not reached when x > 0.6.

Comment: @Builderhummel As Bodo just hinted, it's because your factorial function is overflowing.

Comment: Your stop criterium should be `while (k <= 15);` because k! for `k > 15` (maybe different on _your_ platform) will overflow. Put some printfs at relevant places printing relevant variables and you'll see.

Comment: Quite aside from the overflow difficulties, repeatedly calling `pow(x,k)`, and recomputing the factorial from scratch each time, are both quite unnecessarily inefficient.  You could just keep a running variable containing a term to add in to `res`, and then each time through the loop, multiply it by `x` and divide it by `k`.  That is, incrementally build up the equivalent of `pow(x,k)` in the numerator, and incrementally build up the equivalent of `fak(k)` in the denominator, without ever actually calling `pow` or `fak` to compute either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of your function `fak`. It will overflow and at a certain point return `0`. The division by `0.0` results in `inf`.

When I modify function `fak` as

```
double fak(int n) {
    int f = 1;
    int i = 0;
    
    do {
        i++;
        f *= i;
    } while(i<n);
    
    printf("fak(%d) = %d\n", n, f);
    return f;
}
```

and run it on https://onlinegdb.com/ZxaXfI5xcG, the output is

```
fak(0) = 1
fak(1) = 1
fak(2) = 2
fak(3) = 6
fak(4) = 24
fak(5) = 120
fak(6) = 720
fak(7) = 5040
fak(8) = 40320
fak(9) = 362880
fak(10) = 3628800
fak(11) = 39916800
fak(12) = 479001600
fak(13) = 1932053504
fak(14) = 1278945280
fak(15) = 2004310016
fak(16) = 2004189184
fak(17) = -288522240
fak(18) = -898433024
fak(19) = 109641728
fak(20) = -2102132736
fak(21) = -1195114496
fak(22) = -522715136
fak(23) = 862453760
fak(24) = -775946240
fak(25) = 2076180480
fak(26) = -1853882368
fak(27) = 1484783616
fak(28) = -1375731712
fak(29) = -1241513984
fak(30) = 1409286144
fak(31) = 738197504
fak(32) = -2147483648
fak(33) = -2147483648
fak(34) = 0
fak(35) = 0
inf
```

This means your loop ends when both `res` and `res_old` have the value `inf`.

---

**Additional remark:**

In `func_e` you use `double k;` and pass this to `double fak(int n)` which converts the value to `int`. Function `fak` does the calculation in `int` and implicitly converts the result to `double` in the `return` statement.

I suggest to avoid these conversions. (Or at least think about the possible problems.) The compiler may warn about this if you enable all warnings.